# Geotag an Image

Tags: html, geotagging

I would like to use pure HTML5 to try and test it's ability to Geotag an image with a location. How can this be done in HTML5?

I have used google to find an answer,  but to no avail. I am sure this has been asked before but cant find a similar question and there seems to be very little examples.

I have the retrieving location side of it working, just need to load an image and tag it with the location and save it to local storage.

any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: It's hard. I've never seen it done, though in theory you could do it. It's not trivial.

Comment: Here's how you can access the user's location anyway: http://html5demos.com/geo It doesn't look like it's possible to write exif data/geotag an image, with pure HTML. Try searching Google for something like `php write exif geo`.

Comment: Yeah, the geolocation is easy, but the writing to the file in JS is hard. Writing to the file with PHP is fine.

Comment: Thank you for the fast replies, Looking at the JS way at the moment. Ill justhave to try it and see how it goes. Thanks for your help